# How to corresponding Entity to this new tables

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I'm using EJB and JPA to develop a Java EE project. The server is Jboss AS 7.1 which uses Hibernate as the JPA provider.

In this project, I'd like to add many new tables to the database, I'd also like to add many new columns to these tables at run-time(I don't know which table or cloumn will be added).

**Example1**: I have a table user ,it just have one property id. At run time , I will add properties in runtime according to the need(add a cloumn in user table).

**Example 2**: I'll add a table user_1,I'll also do the same as example1 for user_1(add a table in database).

How can I corresponding Entity to this new tables or new cloumns.There has any method or example?